# How to PIVOT table in BigQuery without "IN" argument

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot

So I have a table that looks like this:

| list | value | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cars | 10000 | 2023-01-28 |
| trucks | 20000 | 2022-12-25 |
| vans | 55 | 2023-01-05 |
| trailers | 560 | 2023-11-11 |

But I want to pivot it so the list value becomes the column and the values becomes the current value column, like this:

| date | cars | trucks | vans | trailers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-28 | 10000 | NA | NA | NA |
| 2022-12-25 | NA | 20000 | NA | NA |
| 2023-01-05 | NA | NA | 55 | NA |
| 2023-11-11 | NA | NA | NA | 560 |

What's the best way to do this? I've tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(select * from `table`)
pivot(sum(list) for list in list)
```

But this didn't work. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try going with the `CASE` expressions:

```
SELECT date, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN list = 'cars'   THEN value END) AS cars,
       MAX(CASE WHEN list = 'trucks' THEN value END) AS trucks,
       MAX(CASE WHEN list = 'vans'   THEN value END) AS vans
FROM <your_table>
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: In my actual data I have 50 lists with a value for every day. Is there not a way to just get a column for every list name without doing a case statement for each? Seems a little clunky

Comment: Then you need to make your pivot expression work. Both have same efficiency nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Use below simple approach

```
select * from your_table 
pivot (any_value(value) for list in ('cars', 'trucks', 'vans', 'trailers'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

you can build that query dynamically (so you will not need to explicitly specify values) and use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to run it - there are plenty examples of such technique here on SO!